# Open design view after closing a solution in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am running windows on a dual boot mac. [this is the solution view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyQsz.png)

I can not open the design view. There is no button and it doesn't load automatically. One suggestion was to press f7 or shift f7 or control f7 none of those have worked. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Wpf or Winforms?

Comment: it is a wcf i believe. i am trying to open the form.cs

Comment: Well try right clicking on Form.cs and open designer or something similar. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: it is not an option. when right clicking. I thought of that too. unless there is a way to open it with "open with..." but i've been clicking the options in there and none of them open it in design view

Comment: it was winforms by the way. wcf was for a different part of my assignmnet

Comment: I figured. Double clicking on Form.cs works for me.

Comment: Does your project have a `.designer.cs` file associated with the form you're trying to design?  I cannot see your screenshot (blocked by firewall).

Comment: yes it does have a .designer.cs

Comment: double clicking in the solution only opens the code. I need the design view.